# Kotlin to Javascript file compilation

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop

Currently, I have two .kt files in a Kotlin/JS project I'm working on. These two .kt files compile to one single .js file (the one in "out/production/myprojectfolder/myproject.js" which is the default directory).

Each of the .kt files represent two separate html pages. I want each of the html page to have its own single .js file.

My question is that, is there a way the two .kt files compile to two separate .js files?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that this is not possible at the moment [[source](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/can-i-have-several-output-files-when-using-kotlin-js/4266)], you can workaround the issue by using multiple modules, but that would mean 1 module per page, which may get complicated quickly.